# In Python, can I make a for loop without the loop variable overwriting current assignment?

Tags: python

I am using a for loop with a variable that is already used, and the for loop overwrites that previously defined variable. I understand that the easy way would be to use a different variable name, but is there another way?

```
x = 999

for x in range(10):
    pass

print(x)
```

> > 9

Comment: No, you can't because its contained within the same scope, read some here https://pythonspot.com/scope/

Comment: If this is the kind of thing that bothers you, you'll probably also hate the fact that `with` and `except` targets are function-scoped and the fact that block scope isn't a thing in general in Python. You'll just have to get used to it; block scope isn't a thing and isn't likely to become a thing any time soon in Python.

Comment: But why do you specifically want to do that in the first place?

Comment: I have a fairly long code and I'm running out of short name variables. But my scope understanding was wrong so I'll operate differently next time. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: If you've got a chunk of code so long you're running out of short variable names, you should 1) refactor that into functions and 2) *stop using short variable names for everything*. Use actually descriptive names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The variable will not be shadowed but assigned to the value of each iteration in the loop. The only corner-case where this is not true is the case where the object iterated over raises an exception before yielding a value.

Answer (score 0):

The variable will be overwritten unless you contain the loop in a different scope

For example, within a function:

```
x = 999

def do_stuff():
  for x in range(10):
     pass

do_stuff()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
999
```

Other than containing the loop in a different scope it's not possible and you will most likely need to rename the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can, but only if you put the for loop in a lower scope, like inside of a function

```
x = 999
def func:
    for x in range(10): pass
print(x)  # 999
```